# How do curse-like effects influence magic item gold piece value?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, pricing

I have created a *Ring of Honest Dungeoneering*, which grants the wearer +2 competence bonuses on multiple skills, but once a week it allows anyone within a 20′ radius to command-word-trigger a *Zone of Truth* with target wearer; obviously, this is detrimental to the wearer. Additionally I’d like to make it hard to remove, e.g. only with a limited wish, wish or miracle.

I cannot find any tables for adding these effects. How would the cost for these effects be calculated?

In response to the comments, it’s worth pointing out that I am talking about a curse-*like* effect, not a curse. The reason it’s only once a week, was to reduce the cost of the permanent spell by ¹⁄₃₅, so it would be affordable for the companions.

The core of the question remains unchanged, though; it is a question about how to adjudicate an items power by its monetary value (as pointed out by one of you, dear users).

Comment: Let me be a honest dungeoneer - the described ring doesn't look THAT cursed. It's limited time per day/week, and it creates a perfectly good spell around the wearer. Even if it affects ONLY him, 1/week use means he just has to ask his best buddy to activate it, and forget the whole ordeal. Make it a constant, nigh-impossible to beat penalty (-10 to Bluff, for example, with the bonuses together being +5), or make the Zone of Truth affect only him and be castable at-will, and it'll look like a proper cursed item. Basically, the curse must mechanically outweigh the benefits

Comment: Do they get the normal save against *zone of truth*?

Comment: Are you a player or a DM?  I know in 3.5, custom magic items are the domain of DMs.  Not 100% sure if that's still true in PF.

Comment: This is a good question; whether the example is balanced or not, the pricing of cursed items can affect Wealth By Level. Plus there's no table in the SRD for cost adjustments.

Comment: @godskook I'm a DM. I've been a (D&D) player perhaps 20 sessions in the last ten years.

Comment: @BenS. That's how I first designed it, but with caster level 10, for a save DC of d20 (or 10) + 12 ( I use active saves for everything, replacing the standard 10 + mods for d20 + mods). It would, though, be better if there was no save allowed. I also considered having the save DC increase by one every time the ringbarer failed, increasing the cost of the ZoT by e.g. 10 %.

Comment: What's the item's role in the campaign? Will it be found as treasure? Will the PCs be made to wear them by their employer?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Originally (when I made it a few years ago), it was meant to be bought by the party to deal with a rogue with fingers just slightly too long.  I remade it today (and made some changes), to be found by the party on a quest to obtain it for someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, first thing first: to count as a cursed, the item has to contain a major flaw that makes it undesirable to most, if not all owners.

The Ring of Clumsiness, for example, gives the wearer a constant Feather Fall, but in turn gives a 20% Arcane Spell Failure chance and -4 Dexterity. A terrible item for a ray-flinging sorcerer, a bad item for a summoner or a rogue, but it's actually not that bad for the party cleric who specializes in battlefield control and ranged attacks via Zen Archery.

Your suggested item, thou, doesn't have an immense drawback for anyone smart enough. It gives skill bonuses, and in turn gives 1/week Zone of Truth useable by anyone but the wearer, plus the standard "can't get it off" deal. I'd say, it should be treated as if the 1/week spell was not a cursed effect (since it can be ignored, or even used by a pair of cooperating players pretty efficiently), with a deduction just for "can't take it off". 100-500 gp (but no more than 10%) off, if I was naming the price.

If it gave a flat Bluff penalty (maybe even a reversed Glibness effect of -30!), that would be a different story, as it would be with a constant, cursed-only ZoT (or at least, at-will ZoT recognizable with, say, a Spellcraft check)

Comment: It would seem that I clearly should add a bonus effect such as negative 10 to 20 Bluff. How would you say such an effect should be treated? Same cost as bonus skill points?

Comment: I'd say that for example if the sum of the bonuses is +8, the penalty should be double that amount (-16) while the cost deduction shouldn't be higher than 33% (it's just one skill, after all) even if we have something akin to -30 to bluff AND a constant personal ZoT effect on top of that. After all, while cursed, this item still gives bonuses.

Answer (score 2):

Normally we don't care about the cost of cursed items much because it's assumed that someone will find them by chance rather than buying them. As @Baka-Mastermind points out, the *zone of truth* effect isn't that bad, and I wouldn't alter the price much for it (it's worth a little more if the ring is easily recognised so anyone can trigger it, and a bit more if they can tell whether the effect had already been used that week, but still not much). The bigger issue that would affect the price is the difficulty of removing the ring, but I still wouldn't take that much off the price - maybe 1,000gp less than a comparable ring?